# pygame continuous rain

Tags: python, pygame

UPDATE 12/16

This codes get the correct effect, but i don't know in new item `new_rain` there no `row` in `new_rain.y` and i remove the `rain`from `Group rains`, so why when i add `new_rain` into `rains` there's still row in it, for i only set `new_rain.y = 0`

```
def check_edge(setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:
                new_rain=Rain()
                new_rain.number=rain.number
                new_rain.row=rain.row
                new_rain.rect.x=new_rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*new_rain.number
                new_rain.y = 0
                new_rain.rect.y=new_rain.y
                rains.add(new_rain)
                rains.remove(rain)
```

I am doing the 13-4 exercise continuous rain, my ideas is to check the every rain's position, first i create a `Group` called `rains` add all item into it, then `blit` it on the screen.

I also store the number and row into the `Group rains` for i can calling it for other method

```
def create(self,setting,rains):
    spacex=setting.w-2*self.rect.x
    numbers=int(spacex/(2*self.rect.x))
    rows=int(setting.h/(4*self.rect.height))
    for row in range(rows):
        for number in range(numbers):
            rain=Rain()
            rain.number=number
            rain.row=row
            rain.rect.x =rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*number
            rain.y = rain.rect.y+2*rain.rect.height*row
            rain.rect.y =rain.y
            rains.add(rain)
```

Then i check the position, if any item in `rains` touch the bottom, remove the item and add new item in it that's make the continuous rain

```
def check_edge(self,setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:
                new_rain=Rain()
                new_rain.rect.x=new_rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*rain.number
                new_rain.y =new_rain.rect.y+2*rain.rect.height*rain.row
                new_rain.rect.y=new_rain.y
                rains.remove(rain)
                rains.add(new_rain)
```

I have 2 rows and 10 columns rain on the screen, but when i run this scripts the first and second loop is correct, the rain really vansihed then create new on the screen

the third loop show an error`AttributeError: 'Rain' object has no attribute 'number'`
I try many times and can't find the reason, for i have defined the `number` and `row` in `Group`

here's the codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame as p
from random import randint

#13-4

class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),p.RESIZABLE,0)
        self.speed = 1
        p.display.set_caption("EXE 13-4")

class Rain(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=p.image.load("../image/rain.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=p.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)/2
        self.y=float(self.rect.y)
    def create(self,setting,rains):
        spacex=setting.w-2*self.rect.x
        numbers=int(spacex/(2*self.rect.x))
        rows=int(setting.h/(4*self.rect.height))
        for row in range(rows):
            for number in range(numbers):
                rain=Rain()
                rain.number=number
                rain.row=row
                rain.rect.x =rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*number
                rain.y = rain.rect.y+2*rain.rect.height*row
                rain.rect.y =rain.y
                rains.add(rain)
        print(spacex)
        print(numbers)
    def check_edge(self,setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:
                new_rain=Rain()
                new_rain.rect.x=new_rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*rain.number
                new_rain.y =new_rain.rect.y+2*rain.rect.height*rain.row
                new_rain.rect.y=new_rain.y
                rains.remove(rain)
                rains.add(new_rain)



    def update(self,setting):
        self.y += setting.speed
        self.rect.y= self.y
    def blit(setting,rains):
        rains.update(setting)
        rains.draw(setting.screen)


def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    rain=Rain()
    rains=p.sprite.Group()
    rain.create(setting,rains)
    while True:
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
        setting.screen.fill((0,0,255))

        rain.check_edge(setting,rains)
        Rain.blit(setting,rains)
        p.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue is that `new_rain` never gets the attributes `.row` and `.number`. Copy the attributes `.number` and `.row` from `rain` to `new_rain`:

```py
new_rain=Rain()
new_rain.number = rain.number
new_rain.row = rain.row
```

---

It is completely superfluous to remove one raindrop from the loop an put a new raindrop in the loop.
It is sufficient to change the coordinate of the raindrop. Move the raindrop to the top of the window, when it reaches the ground:

```py
class Rain(p.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def check_edge(self,setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:
                # put the drop at the top of the window
                rain.y = 0
                rain.rect.y = 0
```

---

If you really want to create completely new raindrops, for what ever reason, then you've to  copy the attribute `.number` from `rain` to `new_rain`. The position of the new raindrop is always at 0, at the top of the window:

```py
class Rain(p.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def check_edge(self,setting,rains):
        for rain in rains.sprites():
            if rain.rect.y == setting.h:

                new_rain=Rain()
                new_rain.number = rain.number

                new_rain.rect.x=new_rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*new_rain.number
                new_rain.y = 0
                new_rain.rect.y=new_rain.y

                rain.kill() # or rains.remove(rain)
                rains.add(new_rain)
```

---

For the initial position the row of the raindrop is important, because the raindrops have to be arranged in different rows. The `y` coordinate of the raindrop depends on the row.
But as soon the raindrops have started falling down, the initial row has no more meaning for the `y` coordinate of the raindrop. It is completely irrelevant where the raindrop has been placed at the beginning. The `y` coordinate of the top of the window is 0 and if the raindrop has to start falling down form the top, its `y` coordinate has to be set to 0.
Note, if a new rain drop is created, then in the top most row, there are not any raindrops, because they have fallen down. The top most row is empty and the new raindrops have to be placed there.
The attribute `.row` is not needed at all and can be removed. The row has only a meaning at the start of the application, when the raindrops are created by `create`. After that the raindrops are falling and continuously change the "row".

Comment: see the ```new_rain.rect.x=new_rain.rect.x+rain.rect.width*rain.number```the ```rect.x``` base on the ```number```, but why when i set ```new_rain.y = 0``` there's no ```row``` in it but the effect still have the same row as before, i have no idea about it

Comment: yes it's working , i have update the question on the top, hardly to understand i havent define the row in ```.rect.y``` but it really have rows in it